# I am getting session not created exception, i am using Kepler version of eclipse, appium 1.6.5 and AVD version 7.0, below are the TestNG error logs:

Tags: selenium, appium

> log:org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create
>   new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities
>   [{appActivity=com.knowarth.hrmsapp.ui.LoginActivity,
>   platformVersion=7.0, androidPackage=com.knowarth.hrmsapp,
>   platformName=Android, device=Android, deviceName=Nexus 5X API 24}],
>   required capabilities = Capabilities [{}] Build info: version:
>   '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800' System
>   info: host: 'KA-LPT-104', ip: '192.168.43.85', os.name: 'Windows 10',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60' Driver
>   info: driver.version: AndroidDriver   at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.lambda$1(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:95)
>     at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)   at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:95)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.doExecute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:111)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:162)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:88)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:112)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:73)
>     at com.ka.tests.Appium_Webinar.setUp(Appium_Webinar.java:42)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

Comment: Have you created the emulator - Nexus 5X API 24?

Comment: Yes, I have created it.

Comment: Is it possible to see the entire appium logs?

Comment: I am not able to add appium log in comment, because its too long.

Comment: [BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: androidPackage, device.
[AndroidDriver] Error: The desired capabilities must include either an app, appPackage or browserName at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow .

Comment: appPackage needs to be added as well. Also looks like device is not there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, you are creating the session but not closing it. Hence when you are running the test for second time, it says "unable to allocate session".

Use these methods to start and stop the appium and it solves your problem.

```
static AppiumDriverLocalService appiumService;
public static void start() throws IOException {
    AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE)
                                   .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.STRICT_CAPS);
    appiumService = builder.build();
    appiumService.start();
    System.out.println("appium server is started");
}

public static void stop() throws IOException{
    appiumService.stop();
    System.out.println("appium server is stopped");
}
```

Comment: I am not able to run even first time. If i use this method to start and stop then where should i add this code, in SetUp() Method?. We do not need to create another method, Right?

Comment: I am using JUnit to run test . So create Appium class and put the above code in it.
   Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException{
        Appium.start();
        // start driver here
    }

    Test
    public void testWhatsNewDoneButton(){
        // Test steps
    }

    After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException{
        Appium.stop();
    }

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolve by downgrading java client version from 5.0.0 to 4.1.2.
Thanks.

Hope this will help you. Happy testing!!